# Have any ideas posted on this site been successfully implemented in a space exploration endeavor?

Tags: discussion

Has any break through been made on Space.SE and incorporated? If so which question or answer was the most helpful?

Comment: I very much doubt it. It's a Q&A site - not an R&D site.

Comment: @JCRM oooohhhh thanks. What R & D site would be good for that?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not really my thing, so I'm not aware of any suitable forums for it.

Comment: I'd say the best bets are in the [tag:cubesat] category. These are often made by small amateur teams, and we have been visited by prospective cubesat designers before with questions of implementation. I have no idea if any of them have taken an idea here, built a cubesat based on it, and have had it flown though.

Comment: R&D is generally not conducted in public. R&D within commercial companies is kept private, universities communicate more but that's usually in the form of presenting the results in a scientific paper. Collaboration is done in invitation-only media (mailing lists, private forums etc.).

Comment: On a site like this, it would be exceedingly unlikely. However, it does happen on other stackexchange sites.

See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow-or-papers-inspired-by-mathoverflow/1917#1917

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to implement [Use or tests of multimode optical fiber for cubesat battery charging or datalink while in storage, or waiting to launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31974/12102) and especially [Could an articulated permanent magnet work as a low-power cubesat magnetotorquer? Problems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17641/12102)